# Creating and pushing a docker image to a google cloud registry using terraform

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create and push a docker image to a Google Cloud Registry using [Kreuzwerker provide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/registry_image) I am able to create the image using the below code (provider settings else where) but when I set the name to the container registry I get an error:

***Error: Error pushing docker image: Error response from daemon: Bad parameters and missing X-Registry-Auth: EOF***

I am finding the documentation quite poor and lacking examples.

```
resource "docker_registry_image" "my_project" {
name = "eu.gcr.io/gcp_project/dockerimage:v1"
build {
context = "${path.module}/filepath"
dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs/resources/registry_image

**Update:**

I ended up using local-exec with a timestamp trigger so the docker command would build and push on each Terraform deployment.

```
resource "null_resource" "docker_build" {

triggers = {
always_run = timestamp()

}

provisioner "local-exec" {
working_dir = path.module
command     = "docker build -t ${local.docker_image} ./my_app/ && docker push ${local.docker_image}"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How is your provider defined? It should include the registry authentication section.

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://localhost:2376"

  registry_auth {
    address = "eu.gcr.io"
    config_file = pathexpand("~/.docker/config.json")
  }
}
```

See https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication on how to create this config.json file if it doesn't exist.
You can also find more information on how to configure registry authentication in Terraform Docker Provider at the [doc main page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs#registry-credentials).